# DataGridView in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview

I am using a data entry Form, which has only one DataGridView. The DGV properties include:

- Name: StaffInfoDGV
- DataSource: StaffInfoBindingSource

The properties of the `StaffInfoBindingSource` are:

- DataSource: StaffInfoDataSet
- DataMember: tblStaffInfo

I can read data without a problem. But, when I modify a value in any column of the grid, and save by clicking save button of `StaffInfoBindingNavigator`, it is not saved and only the original data reappears next time on opening the form.

The following code appears in the Code View of the form:

```
Public Class frmStaffEntry
Private Sub StaffInfoBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StaffInfoBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
Me.Validate()
Me.StaffInfoBindingSource.EndEdit()
Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.StaffEvaluationDataSet)

Me.StaffInfoBindingSource.EndEdit()
Me.StaffInfoTableAdapter.Update(Me.StaffEvaluationDataSet.tblStaffInfo)
End Sub
```

I need help very desperately. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code for Button(Save).Click

```
Dim db As New (DATABASENAME)DataContext
Dim SaveNow As New tblStaffInfo With {.Column1 = txtColumn1.Text, .Column1 = txtColumn1.Text}
db.tblStaffInfo.InsertOnSubmit(SaveNow)
    db.SubmitChanges()
MsgBox("Record Succesfully Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
```

And add this code for Button(Update).Click:

```
Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.StaffInfoBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.StaffInfoTableAdapter.Update(Me.DATAsetNAME.TableName)
        MsgBox("Updated Successfully!", , "Update Successful!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        Me.StaffInfoTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DATAsetNAME.TableName)
    End Try
```

If this doest help try to add text boxes or combo boxes along with your DGV Form and bind them to the same table and try the Button(Update).Click and let me know the result...